# Java Reflection, Class Objects

Tags: java, class, reflection

My objective is to read in to the command line the name of a Class I wish to observe info on.  When I know the class name before runtime, I have no issue.  What I can't seem to manage is how to create a class object based on a string input.

```
public class Tester {

    static void methodInfo2(Object obj) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        //some stuff        
        System.out.print("Test!");

    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        String className = args[0];
        System.out.println("Class:  "+className);

        //myclass2 mc = new myclass2();
        //Class c = mc.getClass();
        Class argClass = Class.forName(className);

        try {
            methodInfo2(argClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

The 2 commented out lines in the main method show what I have done in the past when I know the class name before I compile.  The following uncommented line shows what I thought should work, but I receive a ClassNotFoundException.  The class certainly exists so I'm not sure what problem I'm having.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Make sure you're giving it the fully-qualified name (e.g. `"java.lang.Thread"` and not just `"Thread"`).
2. Make sure the compiled class file is actually on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! For those who find this topic later, my problem was the class I wanted I defined myself within a package in elcipse.  The fix was to append the package name to the beginning of the class name: "packageName.myclass2"

Answer (score 2):

`Class.forName` is the right way to load a class by name at runtime.

Either your argument is wrong or your class isn't in the classpath.